# Android - how to build webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I am using some webviews inside of a ViewFlipper to display some text so I can get full justification and some other aspects of html.

```
WebView welcomeText = new WebView(this);
welcomeText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
welcomeText.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText)).addView(welcomeText);
welcomeText.loadData(getString(R.string.welcome_text), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

And the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16dip" />
```

This works great except for one small annoyance that I wish to eliminate. When I switch to the child view with the webview for the first time on opening the app, the webview height does not seem to be already set so it causes a sort of accordion affect (so the webview kind of quickly slides into place pushing down the rest of the view). Then going to the next child view with a webview and the same happens on that one. Going back to the previous view then works ok with the view already built fully. Im not sure if its related but I also get a webcore warning in LogCat during onCreate

```
"06-04 19:43:48.176: W/webcore(8416): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout"
```

How can I set the webview to be already set with the right heights/widths so when I get to the view it doesnt jump into view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the WebView with layout parameters... Example:

```
WebView welcomeText = new WebView(this);
welcomeText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
welcomeText.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int WEBVIEW_HEIGHT=100;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (WEBVIEW_HEIGHT*density));

((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText)).addView(welcomeText,layoutParams);
welcomeText.loadData(getString(R.string.welcome_text), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: This works in setting the fixed height for the webview, but how can I make it handle orientation? For example, if the view requires a height of 100 in portrait, in landscape it only requires 50.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the orientation like this:

```
int orientation=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

int height;

if(orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    height=50;
}
else {
    height=100;
}
```